# Третьегодняшная бекеша

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Я читал роман Достоевского "Идиот" и встретил там слова "в третьегодняшней отцовской бекеше". Что это значит? Интересно было бы узнать. Особенно слово "третьегодняшная" (если я правильно в именительном падеже написал). Совершенно непонятно.

Процитирую [текст](https://ilibrary.ru/text/94/p.1/index.html).

> — Это вот всё так и есть, — мрачно и насупившись подтвердил Рогожин, —
> тоже мне и Залёжев тогда говорил. Я тогда, князь, **в третьегодняшней
> отцовской бекеше** через Невский перебегал, а она из магазина выходит,
> в карету садится. Так меня тут и прожгло. Встречаю Залёжева, тот не мне чета, ходит как приказчик от парикмахера, и лорнет в глазу, а мы у родителя в смазных сапогах да на постных щах отличались.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бекеша - одежда, меховой полушубок специального кроя (вроде бы обычно носится с головным убором того же меха, тоже иногда называемым бекешей), но это понятно. 
**Третьегоднишний** - тот, чему пошел **третий год**. [Тык](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/280228/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). Здесь намек на ветхость, поношенность.

Образования подобного типа окказиональны, но встречаются в живом языке и общепонятны.

Как вариант - "третьей годности". Но здесь маловероятно по контексту.

~~~~ (немного спустя)

Стоп! Я, кажется, понял. У Достоевского-то третьегодн**Я**шняя. Ударение на я, кстати. *Или даже на первое Е, тогда на Я должно быть побочное.* Вот это интересно... **Третьегодняшний** - это действительно позавчерашний. Неужели ошибся классик? или это особенность речи персонажа?

~~~~ (спустя ещё 15 мин)

Нет, не ошибся. Сообразил. "ТретьегоднЯшний" относилось преимущественно к хлебу, поэтому приобрело переносное значение "черствый" и далее - старый, негодный. Так что и бекеша вполне могла быть **третьегоднЯшняя**.

А вопрос-то интересным оказался. Спасибо!

~~~~ (еще немного)
А смотрите, как изменилось словообразование.
Тогда: 
Третий день - третьего дня - третьегодняшний (сравните: сегодняшний)
Сейчас:
Третий сорт - третьего сорта - третьесортный. 
И еще кто-то жалуется на неумение склонять числительные от двухсот и более )))

Comment: Но ведь в цитате из Достоевского не "третьегоднишний", а "третьегодняшний", то есть речь не о трех годах, а о трех днях?

Comment: Я давно уже добавил.

Comment: > И еще кто-то жалуется на неумение склонять числительные от двухсот и более )))

:-)

> А вопрос-то интересным оказался. Спасибо!

Соглашусь. Очень интересно было почитать рассуждения на эту тему.

Answer (score 1):

При прочтении вопроса у меня возникло такое объяснение:

"третьегодняшняя бекеша отца" - та бекеша, которую надевал отец позавчера, и которую собеседник видел/знает, знает, какая она старая.

Но, кажется, это не подходит к контексту.

Кстати, странно, что кто-то не знает слова "бекеша". Наверное, давно не перечитывал "Как поссорились Иван Иваныч с Иваном Никифоровичем" :-))

Answer (score 0):

Третьегодняшней = третьего дня. Это должно быть очевидно любому русскоязычному человеку.
Вообще же не проблема была самому найти в словаре, что это означает. См. [сюда](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/255637/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Бекеша же слово мне незнакомое и, видимо, устаревшее. Можно посмотреть его значение [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0).

Comment: Уважаемый gecube! Мне кажется, Ваш упрек задавшему вопрос несправедлив. Он ведь, видимо, интересовался не тем, что такое "третьегодняшняя"(по-моему, в именит. падеже должно быть такое окончание)и не тем, что такое "бекеша", а смыслом словосочетания "третьегодняшняя бекеша"? Что это значит? Бекеша, которую не снимали три дня? Бекеша, которую получили или приобрели три дня назад?  Бекеша, которую использовали три дня подряд, не заменяя ее на что-то другое?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Общий смысл -- он и из контекста понятен. Это какая-то одежда, простая у Рогожина, в противоположность Залёжеву. А Рогожину хотелось бы в тот момент перед Настасьей Филипповной (в тексте цитаты -- "она") выглядеть красиво. 

Что бекеша -- это меховая одежда, я уже посмотрел. Но как раз это ясности и не добавляет!

**МЕХОВАЯ ОДЕЖДА -- это не футболка!** :-)  
Это футболку можно **три дня** поносить, а потом хорошо бы и сменить. А меховую одежду? Непонятно, причём тут три дня?

Comment: Думаете, все-таки под третьегодняшней подразумевалось "третьего года"? Тогда неудивительно, что это слово вышло из обихода.

Comment: Как вариант - третьей годности. Но здесь - маловероятно по контексту.

Comment: > Это футболку можно три дня поносить, а потом хорошо бы и сменить. А меховую одежду?

Не уверен на 100%, но вариант 1) она носилась три дня подряд, ес-но, снимаясь дома. вариант 2) была куплена три дня назад отцом.

Answer (score 0):

Или это бекеша, которую отец ПРИОБРЁЛ третьего дня.

Answer (score 0):

Этой бекеше кaк 6ы три года — третьягодняшней бекеше на самом деле больше, нежели три года (три дня образно равняются трём — на самом деле гораздо больше — годам).
То есть речь идёт о старой, заношенной ещё отцом вещи...

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).